# Why is “キャスト” katakana for “cast” rather than “カスト”?

Tags: katakana, english-to-japanese

I was watching *Chuunibyou* (might’ve been something else) and noticed that in the credits there was 「キャスト」written. I thought for a bit and figured it must be “cast”. But why would it be 「キャスト」 with a “kya” rather than 「カスト」with a “ka” ?

Comment: That vowel in English is usually transliterated this way, e.g., キャンプ、キャンパス、キャベツ。But that just begs the question. I'm curious, too.

Comment: Examples of "kya", "gya": cat キャット, carrot キャロット, candy キャンディー, gap ギャップ, gang ギャング/ Examples of "ka", "ga": Canada カナダ, gas ガス/ I could not find how to distinguish which way you should write. At first I thought "ka" and "ga" was usually used in former Japanese, but 宮沢賢治(1896-1933) wrote キャベジ. Maybe "ka" and "ga" words were from other languages, but I could not find any reliable resource that provides information of where a word came from.

Comment: related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5047/30858